# Sum of square $i^2+j^2 = x^2+1$ with $\gcd(i, j) = 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I would like to solve the equation : $$i^2+j^2 = x^2+1$$ for $x, i, j \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\gcd(i, j)=1$

It's obvious that $(i, j, x) = (x, 1, x)$ and $(i, j, x) = (1, x, x)$ are solution yet are there other solutions ? 
Is it possible to list them ?